# SPARC Assembly question

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, sparc

I wanna write a very simple inline assembly routine in my C program which does nothing
else then setting the local registers %l0 - %l7 to different values. I tried the following straightforward approach:

```
asm volatile (
    ".text\n\t"
    "mov 0, %%l0             \n\t"
    "mov 1, %%l1             \n\t"
    "mov 2, %%l2             \n\t"
    "mov 3, %%l3             \n\t"
    "mov 4, %%l4             \n\t"
    "mov 5, %%l5             \n\t"
    "mov 6, %%l6             \n\t"
    "mov 7, %%l7             \n\t"
);
```

unfortuantely, the assembler tells: illegal operand for each instruction. Could somebody please be so nice to point me out how I can properly pass immediate values to the SPARC assembler?

Thanks so much!

EDIT: Thanks Chris, I made the changes you suggested but the Sparc compiler still tells some something about illegal operands...

Comment: Are two %% really necessary here?

Answer (score 2):

SPARC doesn't mave "immediate move" instructions as such; there's either `or` which can be used like `or %g0, 123, %l0` (or'ing a no-more-than 11-bit constant with the zero register, `%g0`, resulting in moving said constant into the target register), or the `sethi` instruction that can be used to set the *upper* 21 bits of a register. In order to accommodate *any* (32bit) constant, you therefore have to synthesise a two-step `set` by doing a `sethi` first for the upper bits followed by an `or` with the lower ones.

SPARC assemblers usually know a `set ..., %tgtregister` shortcut to create this sequence, and/or eliminate one instruction should the constant be fit for that.

Also note that in 64bit / sparcv9, the `set` instruction may ultimately evaluate to a sequence of up to five instructions, shifting/or'ing things together.

Answer (score 0):

You want lines like `mov 0, %%l0` -- source then destination, and constants are just constants, no '#' character.

**edit**

If you have no constraints in your asm directive (just a string), then gcc doesn't process the string for %-escapes.  So in that case you need just single `%` characters before the register name.  But if you add any constraints (or even just `::` after the string -- an empty constraint set), it will look for %-escapes, so you need `%%` for register names.

So either add a `::` just before the `)` or un-duplicate the `%` characters.